# Why do I need a dictionary datatype for input data in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0
X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0
y_train = y_train.astype(np.int32)
y_test = y_test.astype(np.int32)
X_valid, X_train = X_train[:5000], X_train[5000:]
y_valid, y_train = y_train[:5000], y_train[5000:]

dnn_clf = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[300,100], n_classes=10,
feature_columns=feature_cols)

input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
x={"X": X_train}, y=y_train, num_epochs=40, batch_size=50, shuffle=True)

dnn_clf.train(input_fn=input_fn)
```

My question is:
What's the difference between

`x={"X": X_train}, y=y_train, num_epochs=40, batch_size=50, shuffle=True)`

and

`x=X_train, y=y_train, num_epochs=40, batch_size=50, shuffle=True)`

Why can't I just use a **list** `X_train` for the input `x`, but have to convert `X_train` to a **dictionary** `x={"X": X_train}`

Why I don't need to do the same thing for `y`?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation TensorFlow 1.11 for [numpy_input_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn), you can use both approaches. But I've tested it for TensorFlow 1.9 and it didn't work. So, it seems that this functionality was added later.

If I understood, another question was "why x parameter is a map and y is just an array". The thing is that model can have multiple input feature columns/tensors, but the output tensor can be only one. That's true for, at least, standard estimators and for general use-cases. So, you need to somehow specify multiple inputs and the most simple way is just to pass a map.

Comment: Thank you. "the output can be only one", but sometimes we do have multi-feature output?  e.g., input: `(100, 28*28)`, output: `(100, 10)`.

Comment: (100, 10) - that's still one output tensor with the shape (100, 10). Multiple outputs can be, for example, in the object localization task. Such model would predict the location of the object (tensor1 with the shape [batch_size, 4]) and the class of the object (tensor2 with the shape [batch_size, 1000]). I'll update the answer to make it more clear that we are talking about tensors.

Comment: I need to be more clear too. Let's say, the number of samples is `n=100`, input: `(n, 28*28)`, output: `(n, 10)`. For every sample, the input shape is `(1,28*28)`, the output shape is `(1, 10)`.

Comment: If n=100, than there would be only one input tensor with shape (100, 784). For TensorFlow it's just a matrix. And only user of the model knows/interprets this input tensor as a set of 100 samples. The same with output: there is only one output tensor with the shape (100, 10), but only user knows that it's 100 samples. Still not sure that I'm still answering the right question. Let me know if you would like some part of the answer to be extended.